# MySQL multiple OR's in WHERE

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    b.business_name,
    b.address,
    b.city,
    b.state,
    b.phone_number,
    i.date
FROM business_table b
LEFT JOIN inspection_table i ON b.id = i.business_id
WHERE i.date = (
    SELECT MAX(i.date)
    FROM inspection_table i
    WHERE b.id = i.business_id
)
AND b.city LIKE '%Boston%'
OR b.city LIKE '%Dallas%'
OR b.city LIKE '%Seattle%'
OR b.city LIKE '%New York%'
OR b.city LIKE '%Portland%'
OR b.city LIKE '%San Antonio%'
OR b.city LIKE '%Los Angeles%'
OR b.city LIKE '%Miami%'
ORDER BY i.date DESC;
```

I get the result I am after but the query is very slow (~17s). Is there a better way to construct this query? The city field is indexed in the business_table.

Comment: You **could** use a `REGEXP` (`b.city REGEXP 'Boston|Dallas|Seattle'`), but that would actually likely be slightly slower. It shouldn't be taking 17 seconds though; how many rows are in your table?

Comment: ~32,000 rows in my table

Comment: Have you tried putting parenthesis around your OR list; or do you want "the most recent from boston... and everything from every other city"?

Answer (score 1):

A conventional index doesn't help `LIKE '%pattern'` queries at all. The index is not used, and your query must do a complete table-scan of the table.

You need to use [Full-Text Search Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) if you want it to search efficiently using MySQL.

You might like my presentation [Full Text Search Throwdown](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql), in which I compare different methods of text searching for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling your OR is wrong, so this is what I *think* will be the better query.

```
SELECT
    b.business_name,
    b.address,
    b.city,
    b.state,
    b.phone_number,
    li.lastInspection AS `date`
FROM (SELECT business_id, MAX(i.date) as lastInspection
      FROM inspection_table
      GROUP BY business_id) AS li
INNER JOIN business_table b
ON li.business_id = b.business_id
WHERE b.city LIKE '%Boston%'
   OR b.city LIKE '%Dallas%'
   OR b.city LIKE '%Seattle%'
   OR b.city LIKE '%New York%'
   OR b.city LIKE '%Portland%'
   OR b.city LIKE '%San Antonio%'
   OR b.city LIKE '%Los Angeles%'
   OR b.city LIKE '%Miami%'
ORDER BY li.lastInspection DESC
;
```

If you have a **huge** number of cities or businesses, this *might* be slow; but I'd wager an index on `inspection_table (business_id, date)` would speed it up quite a bit.

Ideally, this will get your last inspections, find their business and then filter the businesses; if it doesn't you could force it by putting all but the WHERE conditions in a subquery, and have an outer query do the final filtering.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be multiple problems in the formulation of the query.  The other answers have brought out some of the fixes.  I'll try to address all the problems.

Parentheses is a must -- `x AND y OR z OR w` is treated as `(x AND y) OR z OR w`.  This may fix the intent and the performance.

You are looking for `South Boston` as well as `Boston`?  Also `Boston Heights`?  If not, then get rid of the wildcards (`%`).  This will make it possible to index `city`.

If you *do* need the wild cards, then using a `FULLTEXT` index and `MATCH...AGAINST...` will run a lot faster.

With the leading `%`, I think, the REGEXP suggested Obsidian Age will be faster because it would do only one scan of `city`.

If `business_id` is not the `PRIMARY KEY`, add these:

```
INDEX(business_id, date)
INDEX(business_id, city)
```